# Shared View Model with common observers Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

In my use case, I am using a shared view model with a few common observers. When three fragments are added to the back stack, all three fragments are observed by the view model. However, I only need to observe the current visible fragment.

Need to observe events only in current visible fragment instead of all other fragment observing

Comment: What are you passing to your `.observe` method? Are you passing the fragments as `LifecycleOwner`?

Comment: @mahdi no when any change in live data i'm observing same live data in 3 fragments so only current fragment need to observed the change in live data other fragment should not but thats not happening all 3 fragments are observing

Comment: Why do you want to observe only in current visible fragment? Can you give an example where this will be useful?

Comment: Have you tried passing `getViewLifecycleOwner()` to observe?

Comment: @PawanSinghHarariya I have observer called dismiss which dismiss the fragment, so added in all fragment to observe but only current visible fragment should to observe instead of all.

Comment: @mahdi when fragment is added top of each other it will be in resume state so live data will observe

Answer (score 0):

Shared ViewModels are for sharing common data source among multiple observes. You should not try to observe changes in current visible fragment only, when you have multiple observers of one source. If you do so, data inconsistency may occur.

Suppose you modify the data in the ViewModel in a fragment, if other fragments stopped observing it, they may have old value of data but the data is changed, hence inconsistent data.

What you are trying to do is observe an event, and not state. You want to dismiss the fragment, that is an event. To use LiveData with events, you must reset the value when the event is completed. So, if other observers observe it they don't find that event is occuring. You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/pawanharariya/Guess-Word#event-vs-state). Below is an example :

1. Create a LiveData for the state of event

   ```
   // this is your live data based on which event will occur
   val timer = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()

   // this is the live data for handling the event
   val eventDismissFragment = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()

   init{
      // initialize event to false
      eventDismissFragment.value = false
   }

   // this is the function that is called when the event occurred
   fun onFinish() {
       timer.value = 0
       eventDismissFragment.value = true
   }

   // this is for resetting the value of LiveData after event is handled
   fun onDismissFragmentComplete() {
       eventDismissFragment.value = false
    }
   ```
2. Observe the event instead of timer to dismiss the fragment

   ```
   viewModel.eventDismissFragment.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { isFinished ->
            if (isFinished){
            // dismiss your fragment here but before dismissing
            // notify the ViewModel that you handled the event
            viewModel.onDismissFragmentComplete()

            dismissFragment()
            }
        })
   ```